# HTML element's id after sanitization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-caja

I've been working on a web app with UI built using the Html Service. It's known that HtmlServices uses Caja Sanitization in pre-processing. As a result of this I see that id's of HTML elements are mangled, '-caja-guest-0___' is append to the original id.

I wonder 2 things:

1) What are best practices if I need to be able to get elements by their id's?

2) Can I rely that that suffix will always be '-caja-guest-0___'? Or is there a rule for it?

Thank a lot for all your responses.

Comment: Thank you everybody for answers. Indeed, $("#elementId") works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on any specific things that Caja does because we are and will be making lots of improvements to Caja, which may change how things are implemented. I'd think of any Caja specific changes as private variables in a class you're using: don't rely on them to stay the same.

When working with element IDs, $("#elementId") should just work as expected in jQuery. I would recommend doing this.

Comment: So to be more precise, even if I have multiple caja.load for different <div>s, these divs can all have a child with an id such as 'root-blabla', these elements will be considered, once in the `cage', as elements with different ids ? This would be nice, as I intend to use this with dynamically inserted elements (during the load...), so this means I can reuse the same ids over and over...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using jQuery's "$" function to select elements by the ids assigned in original un-sanitized code and it worked as expected. I think that CAJA also applies the changes to your code so the IDs match

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and document.getElementById should work fine as well. Rule of thumb; don't worry about Caja.